# Auto turn off toggle button when other one is turned on

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have nested toggle buttons which are off by default, when its on it save a value to localstorage. What i want to do is when one is turned on and you try to turn the other on, the first one should be turned off automatically while the other turns on

```
.controller('shops',['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope,$http,$timeout){
$http.get('http://localhost/moves/templates/shopping.php').success(function(data){
       $scope.shops=data ;
        });

 $scope.pushNotification = {};
  $scope.pushNotification.text = "Sample"
  $scope.pushNotification.checked = false;

  $scope.pushNotificationChange = function(item) {
    console.log('Push Notification Change',    $scope.pushNotification.checked);
        if($scope.pushNotification.checked){
            localStorage.setItem("shop_id",($scope.item.shop_id));
        }else{
             localStorage.removeItem("shop_id");
         }
  };


  //$scope.pushNotification = { checked: false };

}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="shops" ng-repeat="item in shops">
          <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap"> 
          <img src="img/index/fashion.png" alt="photo" width="32" height="32" />
          <h2>{{item.shop_name}} </h2>
          <p>{{item.biz_location}}</p>

    <input type="hidden" value="{{item.shop_id}}">

          <div align="right">
          <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
          <input type="checkbox"ng-model="pushNotification.checked"
                    ng-change="pushNotificationChange()">
          <div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div> 
          </label>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          </div>
```

Comment: there is only one checkbox here?

Comment: @AaronSaunders, they or two and can be more

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one checkbox `ng-model` for all your checkboxes, you would want each item to have its own `ng-model` tied to each specific item. That way, when one changes and hits the single change method on the scope, you can update each item's checkbox model however you want (in this case, setting the checked state to false).

Here's a working example, simplifying your existing code in the OP:

```js
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('Shops',['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope,$http,$timeout){

  $scope.shops = [
    {
      shop_id: 1,
      shop_name: 'Shop One',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      shop_id: 2,
      shop_name: 'Shop Two',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      shop_id: 3,
      shop_name: 'Shop Three',
      checked: false,
    }
  ];

  $scope.onItemChange = function(item) {
    // Loop over all our shops and set other checked properties to false if not our current item
    angular.forEach($scope.shops, function(shop) {
      if (shop !== item) {
        shop.checked = false;
      }
    });
    // Do whatever else when an item changes
  };
}]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Shops">
    <div ng-repeat="item in shops">
      <!-- Each checkbox is using a specific model for each item -->
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="onItemChange(item)"> 
      <span>{{item.shop_name}}</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply i had to attend to something. I'm confused because i don't know how to put your answer into my script. i was thinking if you can put it into my script in the question