# making calculation with two fields, one with ng-model in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to add two fields together and get out the sum. but the isssue is when i add ng-model to one of the textfields the binded value in it dissappears. when i remove the ng-model from it the binded values shows up. How do i make the binded values appear in the textfield while using ng-model.

```
<div ng-controller="items" ng-repeat="item in data">
     <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Current Quantity</span>
        <input type="text" value="{{item.quantity}}" ng-model="first">

      </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">New Stock</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="New stock about to be added" ng-model="second">
      </label>
      <br>
     <h1> New Stock: {{first--second}}! </h1>
</div>
```

JS

```
.controller('updatestock_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,$http,$state,$stateParams){
    $http.get('http://localhost/masa/templates/spree/stocks/update_stock.php?item_id='+$stateParams.item_id).success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.data=data;
       });
}])
```

Comment: First, try not using value, but just ng-model: `<input type="text" ng-model="item.quantity">`

Comment: @rgthree Should add as an answer so this question can be shown to have been resolved.

Comment: @rgthree, can you take a look at this question for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644487/auto-turn-off-toggle-button-when-other-one-is-turned-on

Comment: @user6579134 & Lex: Sure thing, added my previous comment as a answer so you can mark this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `value` HTMLAttribute for the input, you should just declare the `ng-model` which will tie the value automatically for both reading and writing:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.quantity">
```